# ansible cron mail on failure

Tags: email, cron

I've a situation where I want cron to send email ON failures only
on a job that was started as part of cronjob.

Here is the snippet I have for ansible yml file.

```
- name: crontab entry to keep sync
  cron:
    name:           support repo sync
    minute:         "00"
    hour:           "03"
    weekday:        "0-6"
    job:            "/usr/local/bin/cronic reposync -r {{ supp_repo }} -l -p {{ repo_path }} \
                     --downloadcomps --download-metadata"
    disabled:       "no"
```

I'm using cronic to ONLY capture the failure cases and want to send an email. I think cronvar or with_items may be useful? Wondering what is
the way to solve this?

Comment: Thanks for comment. Ok, not saying it's ansible problem. But I want cron to send emails with failures (if any). Just to clarify, do I need to add something else to this cron (stanza) wrt to this job to do that task or not? If yes, what is required?

Answer (score 0):

```
#
# Cronvar entries
#
- cronvar:
    name: MAILTO`enter code here`
    value: abc@gandmasti.net
```

The above snippet solved this.

Comment: I must say, pretty interesting domain.